# Using pickerInput's selection to delete leaflet markers

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

I am currently building a dashboard in shiny that consists of a map with certain locations marked out with markers. I also have a pickerInput selection on my sidebar.

I'm trying to make it such that when the user selects a selection from the pickerInput, the marker corresponding to that input disappears.

below is my code: I am not sure how to proceeed

```
#dashboard page
main_page <- nav_panel(
  "cafes",
  card(
    full_screen = TRUE,
    card_header("Please select closed cafes."),
    layout_sidebar(
      sidebar = sidebar(pickerInput("Options", "Select cafes to Close:", choices = location, multiple = TRUE, options = list(container = 'body'))),
      leafletOutput("map")
    )
  )
)
#displaying map
output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    m <- leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lng = default_longitude, lat = default_latitude, zoom = default_zoom)
#adding markers
m <- addMarkers(
      m,
      data = marker_data,
      lng = ~lng,
      lat = ~lat,
      popup = popupGraph(p),
      label = ~marker_data$location
      #icon=marker_icon
    )
```

i also have a marker_data dataframe with 3 columns: lat,lng,location.

Comment: something like `addMarkers(m, data = marker_data %>% filter(!(location %in% input$Options)), ...)` ?